# Android loading string arrays programmatically

Tags: android, string

I have a class called `StringsA` and inside it there is an array of strings:

```
public class StringsA {

static String Names[] = {"Larry", "Moe", "Curly", "John"};  

}
```

In my main class there is a `Button` and a `TextView`.
What I want is to set the text of the `TextView` to a different word from the strings array each time the `Button` is clicked.
For example; the current item is "Moe", when the button is clicked, the `TextView` changes to "John" (the change is random, not by order).

My current Activity code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);        

    Resources i = getResources();
    i.getResourceName(StringsA.Names);

    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {               

        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting error in `i.getResourceTypeName`. How should I change the `TextView` text to one of the strings when the `Button` is clicked?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take full advantage of Android resources, load your values from a string array defined in strings.xml. E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then:

```
  private static final Random RAND = new Random();

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TextView myTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);     

    final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {     
          String nextValue = values[RAND.nextInt(values.length)]          
          myTextField.setText(nextValue);
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Marvin, u helped me =)

Comment: You're welcome. If your question is solved, you can mark the answer as accepted using the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Perfecto Perfecto Perfecto

Answer (score 0):

add the below two lines in onClick method

```
int readomIndex = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
b.setText( Names[readomIndex]);
```