# Get string value from array using positons

Tags: java, android

I have positions like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

I'm fetching array list from res/values/somearray.xml

My question is how can I get the string values from "res/xml/somearray.xml" array using the positions

So far my code:

```
    String checkedids = String.valueOf(group.getCheckedIds()); //group.getCheckedIds() returns Set<Integer> positions basically

for (int i = 0; i < checkedids.length(); i++) {
    if (checkedids.contains("1")) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(valuez)) {
            valuez = valuez + "Fashion";
        } else {
            valuez = "Fashion";
        }
    } else if (checkedids.contains("2")) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(valuez)) {
            valuez = valuez + "Lifestyle";
        } else {
            valuez = "Lifestyle";
        }
    }l

}
```

Result is not accurate with some repeated strings.

My arraylist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="dummy_text">
        <item>Fashion</item>
        <item>Lifestyle</item>
        <item>Beauty and Makeup</item>
        <item>Parenting and Kids</item>
        <item>Pets</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android loading string arrays programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901333/android-loading-string-arrays-programmatically)

Comment: @AnantaRaha No that's quite different

Comment: Check out my answer. Did you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are trying to achieve like following:

```
Set<Integer> checkedids = group.getCheckedIds(); //group.getCheckedIds() returns Set<Integer> positions basically
String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dummy_text);
for (Integer i : checkedids) {
    String stored = values[i-1];
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(valuez)) {
        valuez = valuez + stored;
    } else {
        valuez = stored;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose when I click on fashion the result value in logcat I'm getting is this.

FashionLifestyleBeauty and Makeup

It should return only "Fashion"

Comment: How did you select the positions in your click event? If you have the positions, no need to iterate over the whole array, just `values[position-1]` will give you that string.

Comment: "no need to iterate over the whole array, just values[position-1] will give you that string" Any practical implementation of this?

Comment: Since your post/question seems unclear, it depends on how you handle click from your Views. For example, in your "Fashon" View onClickListener, you can use values[0]; for "Lifestyle", use values[1] etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear about various concepts here. Be clear about the code you write before just writing it. I'll give you the correct solution but you have to infer on what you have done wrong.

You can directly iterate over the set of integers for IDs. The usage of String.valueOf seems wrong here.

```
Set<Integer> checkedIds = group.getCheckedIds();
String[] dummyArrayValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dummy_text);

for(String id: checkedIds){
    if(id > 0 && id <= dummyArrayValues.length){
         if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(valuez))
            valuez = valuez +" "+ dummyArrayValues[id-1]; //Array indexing is zero based so using id-1 to get the correct position according to your example
         else
            valuez = dummyArrayValues[id-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 3 columns in a row.

When I'm clicking on first item of a row I'm getting the whole 3 columns item value in result